# Updating and deleting functions in firestore react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update and delete in firestore via ID with doc data

As of now it prints and it looks like these

```
EHhutrXlEH8x0yjsD1hi Object {
  "AUTHOR": "VINCENT DIZON",
  "CONTENT": "NIXXX",
  "TITLE": "ADMIN",
}

jN7P58zK5JgJGOoDD2aV Object {
  "AUTHOR": "Vincent Dizon",
  "CONTENT": "EXAMPLE ANNOUNCEMENT",
  "TITLE": "Sample Title",
}
```

I need the document Id to be passed on edit function so that I can update it in firestore 
this is my code How to pass Id to update objects to be like code before

```
retrieveAnnouncement = () => {
    const announcements = [];
    const id = []
    /* retrieve announcements */
    firebase.firestore().collection('announcement').get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          announcements.push(doc.data(), doc.id);
        });
        // this will set announcements and trigger render.
        this.setState({ content: announcements, docID: id });
       /*  console.log(announcements) */
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

_renderAnnouncement = ({ item }) => 
    //display the content of announcement
      <Card>
        <Text h3>{item.TITLE}</Text>
        <Text h5>{item.CONTENT}</Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>

        <TouchableHighlight>
            <View>
              <Button title="Edit" onPress={() => console.log(item)}  containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 80}} />
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
          {/* <Button title="Edit" onPress={this.editAnnouncement(item)}  containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 80}} /> */}
          <Button title="Delete" buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 80}} />
        </View>
      </Card>
    render () {
      return (
        <View>
        <ScrollView>
          <FlatList data={this.state.content} renderItem={this._renderAnnouncement} keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
        </ScrollView> 
        </View>
      )}
```

Comment: Can you show your firebase Query? and why can't you pass id as item.id to the editMethod?

Comment: The doc ref is useful for write/delete operations.  Keep that around.  And the ref lets you get at the id (ref.id) whenever you need it.